# User Instance in a connection string gives an error

Tags: asp.net

When program is trying to open the database I get:

Error message: Cannot open database "Chinatowndb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Lee-VAIO\Lee'.

Code is for connection string:

`conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Chinatowndb;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");`

If I change the code to:

`conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Chinatowndb;Integrated Security=True");`

It works.  Now I have another program that uses the first connection string, different database, and it works.  Note that the another program has the .mdf file with the App_Data folder.  Chinatowndb.mdf is store at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA.

Why the error?

Answer (score 0):

For mdf database you must change string connection format, it's not same

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Or 

Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;
```

Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Link :

Answer (score 0):

first one will work if you do this

```
Go to Query Window in SQL Server Management Studio and type this:

exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1. 
Go
Reconfigure
```

Also Read below

[**Using an User Instance on a local SQL Server Express instance**](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

The User Instance functionality creates a new SQL Server instance on the fly during connect. This works only on a local SQL Server instance and only when connecting using windows authentication over local named pipes. The purpose is to be able to create a full rights SQL Server instance to a user with limited administrative rights on the computer.

`Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;User Instance=true;`

To use the User Instance functionality you need to enable it on the SQL Server. This is done by executing the following command: sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'. To disable the functionality execute sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '0'.

Comment: I ran the query, gives the message:  'Configuration option 'user instances enabled' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.'  So it was enabled already?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek- but as stated "works only on a local SQL Server instance" that might be doing some trick over here

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I excluded the `database.mdf` file from project, deleted the `AttachDatabase:database.mdf` from connection string and set `user instance=false`.

Working fine for me. Able to get data from Database.